# Visitor Design Pattern - eCommerce

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, arraylist, visitor-pattern

I'm writing some Java code for an university exam and the project is based on an "e-commerce". 
One of the requirements is to insert the products in the shopping cart and I've to use the `Visitor` pattern.
[image: example visitor]

This is an example that the professor gave me, and I've to "use" it to represent my shopping cart.
The problem is that I've a `Product` class which contain an istance of the `Category` class and products list or categories list are stored in the database (I access to them via query at each step).

Now, first of all ... `book` is a category or a product? It could be compared to *smartphone* or to *htc one m8*, for example?
Also, I've a class that contains all the code "used" by the client. There, I don't have any ShoppingCart object but a simple `ArrayList of Products` related to the user.

How can I implement this pattern in my project? Which is the way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For now nothing ... I've implemented the shopping cart without the pattern ... I'use a simple arrayList of product because I can't understrand how and where I've to modifiy my code.

Comment: I've used some other patterns like singleton and strategy, but, this one, for me, is a problem...

Comment: From the Stack Overflow "Help" page: [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yep, I Know .. but, how can I get some code if I haven't understand what is book:: a product or a category? I grope in the dark...

Comment: I've some code to post, like product class, or category class, or client code part but they are not related to this problem...

Comment: The class is `Book`, not `ATaleOfTwoCities` or `HarryPotterOrderOfThePhoenix`.

Comment: ... and then, I've to substitute at `book`and `fruit`all my single product?
I don't have them in "local" ... I've them in my database. How can I implement it after querying database?

Comment: Why not post loading them from a database as a separate question?

Comment: I can load from a database and I pass to "client" via ArrayList and I visualize it. But ... how can create a new class (like book or fruit) from an ArrayList I think it's impossible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is very simple actually, for example in your main class if the user added 2 elements:

```
    int totalPrice = 0;
    ShoppingCartVisitor cart = new ShoppingCartVisitorImpl();
    ItemElement element1 = new Fruit(2,3,"Apple");
    ItemElement element2 = new Book(30,"some ISBN number");
    totalPrice += element1.accept(cart);
    totalPrice += element2.accept(cart);
```

In both Fruit and book you add:

```
public void accept(ShoppingCartVisitor v) {
    v.visit(this);
}
```

and in ShoppingCartVisitorImpl :

```
public int visit(Book b) {
     return b.getPrice();
}

public int visit(Fruit f) {
     return f.getPricePerKg()*f.getWeight();
}
```